# Let onBackPressed() close application

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have an application that uses fragments. On app launch I do this:

```
    FragmentManager man = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction trans = man.beginTransaction();
    trans.replace(R.id.master_container, master);
    trans.commit();
```

As you can see I don't add it to the Backstack because I don't want users to be caught in an empty activity with no fragment. However that doesn't work. Because when I press the backbutton in the `master` screen it will close the fragment and leave me in a black activity.
Now I override the `onBackPressed()` method to help me:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // 'master' is the Mainscreen Fragment
    if (master.isVisible()) {

        if (!second) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Press back again to close application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            second = true;
        } else {
            second = false;
            CreamyActivity.this.finish();
        }

    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        bar.show();
    }
}
```

But whenever `CreamyActivity.this.finish();` it again just closes the fragment and drops into the blank activity (as if it was just following the backstack) (This is all in the Activity btw!)

I was wondering if you could help me. Usually apps shouldn't close themselves but I would really appreciate a workaround here. Or am I doing something wrong with the backstack? Does it automatically add it anyways?

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Call this `CreamyActivity.this.finish();` after `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: Hmm, noep. Doesn't help :( It follows the backstack, removes one item and then just get's stuck there. Funnily enough the `CreamyActivity.this.finish();` must be closing the fragment because the other `super.onBackPressed();` from further down below never is called

Comment: "However that doesn't work. Because when I press the backbutton in the master screen it will close the fragment and leave me in a black activity" -- the BACK button will `finish()` your activity if you do not have fragment transactions on the back stack, as you can see by running any number of sample apps, such as: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Fragments/Dynamic (see `OtherActivity`). Something else in your app is interfering with this behavior. My guess is that BACK is actually exiting your activity, but returns control to some other activity you forgot about. :)

Comment: Hmmm.interesting though. I do have one other activity in my application so far. When the app launches there is a quick checkup if the API level is > 4.0 or not. "CreamyActivity" will actualy only launch when the user has IceCreamSandwich (*badum-tss* really bad joke xD). So maybe it's returning into that? If so, would the most elegant way be to send an intent to the second activity while `finish();` is being called on the `CreamyActivity` to trigger the initial LaunchActivity to close as well? Or is there a better way? Thanks for the input so far btw:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay as CommonsWare (Thanks to you!) pointed out there WAS something else interfering with the workings of the application. It's structured like this:

App Launch --> LaunchActivity if(API > 14) --> CreamyActivty

else --> CrunchyActivity

When calling finish() in CreamyActivity it made the App go back to the LaunchActivity which didn't have anything else in it's onCreate() other than the if-else statement. Now I've done this:

To my LaunchActivity I added:

```
    private IntentFilter filter;

    filter = new IntentFilter(Util.BACKSTACK_INTENT);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            LaunchActivity.this.finish();
            unregisterReceiver(this);

        }
    }, filter);
```

And into the onBackPressed() method from the Creamy/Crunchy Activities I added this:

```
            CreamyActivity.this.finish();
            Intent kill = new Intent();
            kill.setAction(Util.BACKSTACK_INTENT);
            this.sendBroadcast(kill);
```

Like this every time the user wants to go out of the application it will send an intent back to the LaunchActivity and terminate that one as well.

Again. Thanks a lot to CommonsWare for pointing out the flaw in the previous design :P Hope this helps somebody.